# Handling properties by YAML file

Tags: java, yaml

I learn how to handle properties, on a test project, that are written in a yaml file.

I know that it is very similar to handling JSON files.

I learned that I have to write a class/objects composition model that will mirror the yaml configuration.

I did it, and I have to say that everything works pretty well but suddenly I've met a difficulty.

I mean, what if I will add a new property to yaml, that will not have a mirror object in a composition model?

I want to write a code that will read the property just after I will add it to yaml, and I have no idea how to do that.

Does anybody have some suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for *named* properties, you're out of luck. You need them in your class. However, you can use some more generic collections instead, and fetch the properties by name, assuming they're something simple like key/value.

For example, if you have YAML like this:

```
size: 16
crust: "wheat"
toppings:
  "cheese": "normal"
  "pepperoni": "normal"
  "onion": "normal"
  "mushroom": "extra"
```

You *could* have a fixed set of toppings like this:

```
public class Pizza
{
  private int size;
  private String crust;
  private Toppings toppings;
}

public class Toppings
{
  private String cheese;
  private String pepperoni;
  private String onion;
  private String mushroom;
}
```

But in reality, we all know everyone wants something different on their pizza. If you were to only have the same pizza for everyone, you'd go out of business. So, you need something a little more flexible for toppings. Sometimes they'll be there, sometimes they won't be. So, you have to use a more flexible data structure:

```
public class Pizza
{
  private int size;
  private String crust;
  private Map<String, String> toppings;
}
```

Most serializers (e.g. Jackson) know what to do with collections like `Map` or `List`. They'll allow you to add *whatever* property you want, so long as it fits the form/type of the collection.